# Auto sync and GPS in android

Tags: android

Can anyone provide me some code snippet for enabling/disabling auto sync and GPS in android? I have been trying for long but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

without intervention by the user, this is not possible, but you can start the Intent for the settings

```
Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS); 
this.startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
```

Comment: ya that is the thing na....i wanted to control it directly...
i have seen many apps in market which do it.

Comment: you are able to turn on GPS if it's already enabled, but if GPS is completly disabled, a application shoudn't be able to enable it by itself, if there are applications who do that, they are supposed to use an exploit. Tell me one of them, sounds strange...